# Python Tkinter passing self as button command parameter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, command, self

I have a noob question:

I am trying to make a class "Field" that inherits everything from Tkinter's Button class but also contains the additional attribute "location" and a method to get that attribute. Having implemented that, I make in instance of the new "Field" class and try to have the Field's command call its function to get its location attribute:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Field(Button):
    def __init__(self, location, **k):
        Button.__init__(self, **k)
        self.location = location

    def getLoc(self):
        return self.location

root=Tk()
c = Field(2, text="Text", command = lambda: self.getLoc)
c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The root window with the button appears but upon pressing it, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\test2.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    c = Field(2, text="Text", command = lambda: self.getLoc)
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

What should I do to make it see the fact that I want the recently instantiated "Field" to be the "self" whose location it should return?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** sorry I was completely off about the original response about doing `lambda self: self.getLoc`, corrected answer (and checked by running the code this time!)

You should probably configure the command after you create the button, that way you can explicitly refer to the button.

```
root=Tk()
c = Field(2, text="Text")
c.config(command=c.getLoc)
c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

You can read more about the config method of Tkinter objects (and much more) on [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method).

Comment: Thanks! It helped. I guess it makes sense, since the "self" doesn't really exist yet when I am trying to pass the command during the Field instantiation. Also thank you for the config info, definitely going to come in handy. 
(My apologies for lack of +1, cannot do due to low reputation :()

Comment: Hello there! I am experiencing a similar issue but for a button, not a field. When I tried the code above, replacing the `Field`s with `Button`s, I got an error saying that the buttons don't have the `getLoc` property. Can somebody guide me in the right direction? Thanks!